# Как загрузить видео в бд mysql на php?

Tags: php, mysql

Как загрузить видео в бд mysql на php?У меня есть уже готовый сайт осталось только загрузка видео в бд с загрузкой его(видео) на сервер, при этом у меня есть 2 формы выбора файла и мне нужно чтобы я нажал на 1 кнопку , а загрузилось 2 фото, и видео, вот мои формы загрузки:

```
<form action="load_video.php" method="post">
    <p>Обложка видео</p>
    <input type='file' name='uploadfile_img_video'><br>
    <p>Видео</p>
    <input type='file' name='uploadfile_video'><br>
    <p>Название видео</p>
    <input name="name_video" type="text"><br>
    <p>Описание видео</p>
    <textarea name="description_video" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button name="add_video_btn">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Зачем класть видео в бд? Почему не в файл?

Answer (score 2):

В бд вы никак не загрузите. БД хранит только информацию. Алгоритм такой:

1. Вы отправляете post запрос на сервер с вашими видео+фото.
2. С помощью php вы загружаете видео и фото на сервер ([Клик](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php))
3. Сохраняете ссылки загруженных файлов в бд.